# Luracast Restler Multiformat XML not returned

Tags: php, web-services, rest

i have a question regarding Luracast Restler v2.

I have created my index.php with the following content:

```
require_once 'framework/restler.php';

spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload');

$r = new Restler();
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat');
$r->addAPIClass('PROCESSOR');
$r->handle();
```

Now i have my processor.php with the following code sample - **this is just a small part of the codebase**! :

```
class PROCESSOR {
    private $api_ver    = '0.1';
    private $allowed    = array('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');

    public function index( $request_data ) {
        if(empty($request_data)) throw new RestException(400,"parameter missing");
        $this->checkHost();
        $this->get_vars = $request_data;

    $result = new stdClass();               
    $result->version    = $this->api_ver;
        $result->timestamp  = date(DATE_RFC822);
        $result->generated  = $totaltime.' sec.';
        $result->type       = 'success';
        $result->filesize   = $this->res_filesize;
        $result->url        = $this->res_saved; 

        return $result;     
    }
}
```

My Problem is now, that when i send the request to 
http://api.myserver.xx/processor/?url=http://www.test.fr

The API does what it has to do and returns JSON string.

But when i type 
http://api.myserver.xx/processor**.xml**/?url=http://www.test.fr
it also returns JSON - and not XML?!?

What's wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `JsonFormat`, `XmlFormat` is not contained in `restler.php` it is present in `xmlformat.php` make sure you have copied it to the same folder as `restler.php` and if it is still not working try including that class also manually

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while dealing with the same issue. I have located an issue with the code, at least with the GitHub code retrieved on 13 Feb 2012. In the `restler.php` class function `getResponseFormat()`, starting at line 503, the extensions are pulled from the request url.

The first line in the while loop (512) extracts the `".xml"` extension just fine, but the following lines manipulate the variable so when the conditional statement evaluates `$extension`, it is no longer the expected value. I simply added a variable after the first line in the while loop to hold the original value of extension, then check if that value exists in the `$format_map`. The example project works as expected once doing this.

FYI, I do not think this is a platform dependent issue, but if so, here is my environment:

```
OS: Mac OSX 10.7.3
PHP: v5.3.6
Apache: 2.2.21
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rhoderunner: I think the more precise bug is in line 514 of the restler.php file. This line has to be:

```
$extension = array_shift($extension);
```

and **NOT**:

```
$extension = array_shift($extensions);
```

So we have to get rid of the **s**.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, just fixed it in Restler 2.1.3

Comment: You're welcome. I realy like Restler and we're using it in our new soon to be released CMS called Spike: [spikecms.com](http://www.spikecms.com)

Comment: Eager to know more about SpikeCMS, it can be a great case study for Restler

Comment: @Luracast We hope to launch the first beta in the beginning of april, bt I saw you subscribed to our mailinglist, so we'll keep you posted!